# Paragraph separation with "article" document class

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I'm writing a text but it seems the document class "article" doesn't allow for paragraph separation. Is there any way to force the paragraphs to have an space between (even in the abstract)?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\bibliographystyle{nature}      

\usepackage{lipsum} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template

%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
%\linespread{1.05} % Line spacing - Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,columnsep=28pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=10mm} 

\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF

\usepackage{paralist}% Used for the compactitem environment which makes bullet points with less space between them

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\Roman{subsection}}% Roman numerals for subsections
%\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyhead[C]{VIZIDI $\bullet$ Generative Art \& Design $\bullet$ Winter Semester 2013/2014}  % 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{VIZIDI}} % Article title

\author{
\large
\textsc{David Beerman \& Antonio Palacios}\\[2mm] % Your name
\normalsize Hochschule für Künste Bremen \\ % Your institution
\href{mailto:antonio@killthepixelnow.com}{antonio@killthepixelnow.com}\\
\href{mailto:mail@davidbeermann.com}{mail@davidbeermann.com} % Your email address
\vspace{-5mm}
}
\date{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Insert title

\thispagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract}

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

Donec vitae justo ac elit imperdiet ullamcorper eget vitae ante. Nam elementum condimentum sagittis. Suspendisse nibh enim, ultricies nec iaculis eu, elementum in mauris. Proin faucibus rhoncus dolor in ultricies. Curabitur interdum justo non dui rutrum pharetra quis vitae risus. Mauris odio massa, luctus et odio vitae, porta aliquam massa. Sed aliquam ligula enim, a fringilla tellus vulputate at. Aenean vitae rutrum lectus. 

\end{abstract}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{multicols}{2} % Two-column layout throughout the main article text

\section{Introduction}

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Methods}

\subsection{Parsing MIDI files}
Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

\subsection{Evaluating MIDI data}
Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

\subsection{Visualization and animation}
Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Discussion}

A good point of discussion here concerns the level of technical complexity of the pieces that were exhibited alongside VIZIDI in the “Generative Art \& Design” space. It was interesting to appreciate that people oftentimes reacted more positively to projects that favoured aesthetics. In that sense, a possible question would be: should visual impact be the goal of generative art? There is no doubt that this is a controversial issue. An engaging experience, a room full of colorful lights or a breathtaking animation are only possible if a good program has been compiled. Therefore, code and visuals must work in tandem. Reaching that balance is perhaps the most difficult part of any job of this nature.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCE LIST
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\bibliography{vizidi} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is hardly minimal but I've gone with it anyway.

`parskip` is the recommended way to use vertical spacing for paragraph separation:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\bibliographystyle{nature}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template

%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% you cannot use 2 input encodings simultaneously!
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
%\linespread{1.05} % Line spacing - Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[columnsep=28pt]{geometry} % Document margins % don't load geometry twice
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=10mm}% sets margin ratio again in effect

\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF

\usepackage{paralist}% Used for the compactitem environment which makes bullet points with less space between them

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\Roman{subsection}}% Roman numerals for subsections
%\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers - THIS command sets the default page layout
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyhead[C]{VIZIDI $\bullet$ Generative Art \& Design $\bullet$ Winter Semester 2013/2014}  %

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{VIZIDI}} % Article title

\author{
\large
\textsc{David Beerman \& Antonio Palacios}\\[2mm] % Your name
\normalsize Hochschule für Künste Bremen \\ % Your institution
\href{mailto:antonio@killthepixelnow.com}{antonio@killthepixelnow.com}\\
\href{mailto:mail@davidbeermann.com}{mail@davidbeermann.com} % Your email address
\vspace{-5mm}
}
\date{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Insert title

\thispagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers  - no this command only affects THIS page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract}

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue.

Donec vitae justo ac elit imperdiet ullamcorper eget vitae ante. Nam elementum condimentum sagittis. Suspendisse nibh enim, ultricies nec iaculis eu, elementum in mauris. Proin faucibus rhoncus dolor in ultricies. Curabitur interdum justo non dui rutrum pharetra quis vitae risus. Mauris odio massa, luctus et odio vitae, porta aliquam massa. Sed aliquam ligula enim, a fringilla tellus vulputate at. Aenean vitae rutrum lectus.

\end{abstract}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{multicols}{2} % Two-column layout throughout the main article text

\section{Introduction}

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Methods}

\subsection{Parsing MIDI files}
Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue.

\subsection{Evaluating MIDI data}
Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue.

\subsection{Visualization and animation}
Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue.

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue.

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Discussion}

A good point of discussion here concerns the level of technical complexity of the pieces that were exhibited alongside VIZIDI in the “Generative Art \& Design” space. It was interesting to appreciate that people oftentimes reacted more positively to projects that favoured aesthetics. In that sense, a possible question would be: should visual impact be the goal of generative art? There is no doubt that this is a controversial issue. An engaging experience, a room full of colorful lights or a breathtaking animation are only possible if a good program has been compiled. Therefore, code and visuals must work in tandem. Reaching that balance is perhaps the most difficult part of any job of this nature.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCE LIST
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\bibliography{vizidi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: parskip]

## Notes

- Don't load a package twice e.g. `geometry`.
- `\thispagestyle` affects only **this** page style.
- `\pagestyle` affects the default page style.
- You cannot use 2 input encodings simultaneously so don't tell `inputenc` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Though you caould use the `parskip` package, the safest thing to do here would be to switch to `scrartcl` and use one of its `parskip` options (there's `half`, `full` and some `+` and `*` variants):

```
\documentclass[twoside,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\bibliographystyle{nature}      

\usepackage{lipsum} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template

%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
%\linespread{1.05} % Line spacing - Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,columnsep=28pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=10mm} 

\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF

\usepackage{paralist}% Used for the compactitem environment which makes bullet points with less space between them

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\Roman{subsection}}% Roman numerals for subsections
%\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyhead[C]{VIZIDI $\bullet$ Generative Art \& Design $\bullet$ Winter Semester 2013/2014}  % 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{VIZIDI}} % Article title

\author{
\large
\textsc{David Beerman \& Antonio Palacios}\\[2mm] % Your name
\normalsize Hochschule für Künste Bremen \\ % Your institution
\href{mailto:antonio@killthepixelnow.com}{antonio@killthepixelnow.com}\\
\href{mailto:mail@davidbeermann.com}{mail@davidbeermann.com} % Your email address
\vspace{-5mm}
}
\date{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Insert title

\thispagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract}

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

Donec vitae justo ac elit imperdiet ullamcorper eget vitae ante. Nam elementum condimentum sagittis. Suspendisse nibh enim, ultricies nec iaculis eu, elementum in mauris. Proin faucibus rhoncus dolor in ultricies. Curabitur interdum justo non dui rutrum pharetra quis vitae risus. Mauris odio massa, luctus et odio vitae, porta aliquam massa. Sed aliquam ligula enim, a fringilla tellus vulputate at. Aenean vitae rutrum lectus. 

\end{abstract}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{multicols}{2} % Two-column layout throughout the main article text

\section{Introduction}

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Methods}

\subsection{Parsing MIDI files}
Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

\subsection{Evaluating MIDI data}
Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

\subsection{Visualization and animation}
Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

Nunc orci nibh, gravida non euismod gravida, elementum quis nibh. Nulla dui ipsum, dignissim at elit sed, consequat vestibulum purus. Morbi elementum leo consectetur ipsum fermentum sollicitudin. Etiam feugiat est ac risus congue, convallis sagittis est rutrum. Donec consectetur sodales velit ut vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur aliquam nunc quis placerat adipiscing. Proin scelerisque, magna in luctus faucibus, libero justo tincidunt ante, nec imperdiet augue massa in augue. 

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Discussion}

A good point of discussion here concerns the level of technical complexity of the pieces that were exhibited alongside VIZIDI in the “Generative Art \& Design” space. It was interesting to appreciate that people oftentimes reacted more positively to projects that favoured aesthetics. In that sense, a possible question would be: should visual impact be the goal of generative art? There is no doubt that this is a controversial issue. An engaging experience, a room full of colorful lights or a breathtaking animation are only possible if a good program has been compiled. Therefore, code and visuals must work in tandem. Reaching that balance is perhaps the most difficult part of any job of this nature.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCE LIST
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\bibliography{vizidi} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

When I say "safer" I mean the following: using `full` or `half`, means the additional separation between paragraphs will be of one line or only half of a line, respectively. Besides the class taking care of not increasing the spacing at undesired locations (lists, and ToC, LoF, LoT, for example), using modifiers `*`, `+`, Without any modifier, the last line of a paragraph will end with white space of at least `1em`. With the plus character, the white space amount will be a third, and with the asterisk a fourth of the width of a normal line. This avoids the ambiguity that might result from a last line extending all the way to the right margin just before a page break.

Comment: Could you explain why it is safer?

Comment: @cfr I added some explanation about what I meant by "safer".

Comment: Thanks. I knew `parskip` took care of the spacing for environments. I hadn't thought of the ambiguity at the end of a page. (I use this style for fairly limited purposes such as handouts where that isn't really an issue.)

Comment: Thanks, that was a neat solution. I'm still tweaking the style but it looks better now.